# How does the Master Sword durability work?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I intentionally worded the title like that to avoid spoilers, so here goes the spoiler:

> The Master Sword needs to recharge its energy when you use it too much. How exactly does that work? At some point you get a message, similar to weapon durability, "Your Master Sword is running low on energy" and finally after more usage that it ran out. How long does it take to fully charge? Can I speed up the process? It seems like I can almost never use it, because the recharge takes so long.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> It takes 10 real time minutes for the Master Sword to recharge after "running out of charge". This cannot be sped up.

Bigger spoilers ahead:

> Note that when fighting Guardians, Divine Beast bosses, and Ganon, the blade will glow Blue and the damage will double to 60. While in this state, it has greatly increased durability and can be used for a great amount of time, as long as it hitting the above enemies. Hitting rocks etc while the blade is glowing blue will still lose durability at a normal rate.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! Additional question: Does it recharge constantly, even if it is only "partly out of charge"?

Comment: @ian_itor As far as I know, only when it is out of charge.

Comment: Oh, that sucks. So I should basically, if I ever use it against non-special targets, deplete it completely? That explains, why it seemed to me to take ages to recharge... cause it never did.

Comment: I totally broke the master sword while farming wild guardians yesterday. The sword was glowing blue, I didn't hit any rock or tree and it sure broke.

Comment: It seems to be completely indestructible when you're in Hyrule Castle. Perhaps the presence of the calamity all around you keeps it in its fully charged state.

Comment: No, scratch that. It seems that it becomes _very_ durable while at the castle.

Comment: Also, if you derp with it and hit a shield with it, that counts towards depletion, so be a good fighter!

Comment: It sill loses durability while fighting divine beast bosses as i was fighting against windblight ganon and the sword broke, so I dont know what that light is but it does not mean infinite durability.

Comment: You can check the reload-time for the sword and abilities in the menu (after you expended them) :)

Comment: You could possibly add that with the DLC trail of the sword you can increase the durability of the master sword so it lasts longer.